# How to print value in exponential notation?

Tags: python

I have this:

```
print('bionumbers:',bionumbers)
```

which outputs:

bionumbers: 9381343483.4

How can I output this value in exponent notation?

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332056/decompose-a-float-into-mantissa-and-exponent-in-base-10-without-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Python3 format syntax :

```
print(f'bionumbers: {bionumbers:e}')
```